# Is there a limit to the force of a lodge you create?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I've been wondering if there is a limit on how powerful the lodge you create can be? Is it limited by the magic rating of the mage/shaman who creates it? Or can it be as strong as the amount of Lodge materials the constructor has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to how long you want to spend preparing your lodge (or how much time you have available) and how much dough you're willing to spend.

You determine the Force of the lodge when you create it.  You spend Force x 500¥ on lodge materials, and spend a number of days equal to the Force of the lodge building and preparing the lodge.  The Force of the lodge is used to determine the strength of the mana barrier surrounding it, as well as the Force limit for any rituals cast within the Lodge. *Pg 208, Shadowrun 5e Core Rulebook.*

Outside of that, it can be any value, but if you want to use it for ritual casting, you'll want to make sure that the Force of the lodge equals or exceeds the Force of the ritual. *Pg 296, Shadowrun 5e Core Rulebook.*

Comment: Also, the Avail for the materials is two times the force rating of the lodge you want to create.

Comment: You can also increase the lodge later on by spending (difference in Force x 500) nuyen. It's unclear whether the availability is also (difference in Force x 2) or (total Force x 2), both most people rule it as the latter to avoid players building a Force 40 lodge in Force 2 increments to keep the availability low.